# Windows 8 Lock Screen randomly activates "something" that jams Password Entry

Tags: windows-8, passwords, windows-8.1

My system is currently running Windows 8.1, and since the update, I have been encountering an odd problem.

I lock my system whenever I am not present (basic security), but when I come back to it, sometimes I cant enter my password.

I can enter capital letters into, but any other key pressed without `shift` doesn't get entered. I have found the only way to remedy this is to go into the `Accessibility` settings at the bottom right, start the `Narrator`, hit the link twice (so it opens the Narrator Window), then close the Narrator, and I can enter my password fine. It also gets resolved if I click the "back" link to change User, then select my profile and I can enter my password again.

Does anyone know what is causing the problem? I think it might have something to do with another Window (or part of the Login Screen) being focus, and I usually hit `space` to go from my pretty pictures to my Password entry, and that act is activating some linked procedure.

Comment: Right, so I have just tried disabling `Narrator` by modifying the Execute permissions, but it didn't fix the problem. But, I did find out that while holding down `Shift`, I can enter characters uppercase, and if I turn on `Caps Lock`, I can enter the lowercase characters. Its like the system has locked the `Alt` key on, and no matter how many times I press any other alt key, it doesn't turn off. Its only turned off once I have unlocked mycomputer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, at some point during the lock screen, I must have bumped the `Windows` key, which when you're on the lock screen puts the keyboard into `alt` mode. Pressing the `Windows` key a few times fixes it!

Comment: I have figured out the cause. It was when I lock my workstation using `Windows + L` while in Team Viewer